# strtotime php functions outputs good time in php file but wrong after update in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

Ive got such script:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx');
mysql_select_db('xxx');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rl_cronjobs";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$sunday = $row['next_sunday'];
$today = date('Y-m-d');


if($sunday == $today){
    $sql = "DELETE * FROM xxx WHERE stala != 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $nextsunday;
    $nextsunday = strtotime("next Sunday");
    $nextsunday = date('Y-m-d', $nextsunday);   
    $sql = "UPDATE xxx SET next_sunday = $nextsunday";
    $sql = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $nextsunday;
}
```

And in MySQL the value of it is: 1984
I need it to be normal date of next sunday

The type of MySQL table row is varchar because when i set tu date it doesn't update. Any help?

Comment: `1984 = 2012 - 12 - 16` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store dates in varchar fields. Mysql has date, datetime, and timestamp fields for such things, and using them opens a world of new possibilities. E.g. your "next sunday" calculations can be done as simply as:

```
UPDATE xxx SET next_sunday = NOW() + INTERVAL (8 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) DAY
```

without ever involving the PHP time functions. Note that this particular function will always pick the real next sunday, so if you run this code on a Sunday, you'll get the following weeks' sunday, not "today", e.g.:

```
'2012-12-08' (Saturday) -> '2012-12-09'
'2012-12-09' (Sunday)   -> '2012-12-16'
'2012-12-10' (Monday)   -> '2012-12-16'
```

As well, note that you're trying to echo `$nextsunday` before it's been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missing some quotes `"` or `'` in your update query. You probably meant to write:

```
$sql = "UPDATE xxx SET next_sunday = '$nextsunday'";
```

*sidenote:* The `myslq_*` functions are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated), you shouldn't use them in new code anymore.